# Perforce: P4V option to 'add to client view'? (It exists in P4Win)

Tags: perforce, p4v, p4win

In the Perforce realm, the P4Win GUI is now "legacy" and the new P4V is supposed to fill in the void (and it does, most of the time).

There was one very useful (albeit rather hidden) option in P4Win that allowed adding a depot path to the client specification in a few clicks.

Is there a similar option available in P4V? ... because I can't find it.

(I know I can do it manually.)

Here is the P4Win feature, in all its glory:

[image: P4Win showing 'Add files to client' option]

Comment: You might want to open a support request at Perforce for that feature. They are pretty willing to get rid of short-comings in p4v.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is typical for the P4 GUI (old and new) - it can do lots of things, if only you knew where to look (hint: usually not where you'd expect to find it).

There *IS* an option in P4V similar to the old 'Add Files to client view' from P4Win, only a lot more powerful! (it's a bit hidden and IMO not as streamlined as the original)

You can't find it in the depot view, where you probably ARE when you need it. Instead, go to Workspaces view, right-click the workspace definition and 'Edit' it (or dbl-click it then click 'Edit').

Notice the tabs on top of the 'Workspace editor' window that just opened. Select the 'View' tab. There is a *lot* going on here, including (apparently) information on the new 'Offline' mode.

To get to the point: in this window, find the piece of depot you need and right-click it.

**Nirvana!** There are no less than **6** menu options (!) that allow you to specify how and what to add OR remove to/from the workspace definition.

[image]

There's even an 'advanced' mode that looks a bit scary :-&

[image]

Comment: Why did I never notice this tab??! Good answer!

Comment: @rmx, Don't feel bad; I didn't notice the tab either.  I even went to the trouble to email a Feature Request to Perforce asking for a file tree browser to include/exclude directories in the depot path, to which they responded with this dialog.  I requested that the tab be more prominent.

Comment: The only tabs I have in the workspace editor are `Basic` and `Advanced`. I use P4V version `Rev. Perforce Visual Client/MACOSX106X86/2012.2/527787`. I guess I misunderstood your answer, but what did I miss?

Comment: @Jean-Denis No experience with p4's Mac client, unfortunately. (+ I switched shops, and the new one doesn't use P4) Maybe ranjit's answer below may offer a starting point?

Comment: Thanks for the nice answer. ranjit's answer doesn't help very much. I want to tell Perforce to ignore my .git directory and its content. Workspace mappings seems to have an "exclude" button too, but clicking it, I cannot see the .git repository, perhaps because it's an invisible directory. Catch 22 perhaps.

Comment: @Jean-Denis well, you could try to edit the client spec manually. I seem to remember that adding a - (minus) in front of a line means "exclude this from the spec"

Comment: @Jean-Denis See here: (long page, search for "Excluding files and directories") http://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.current/manuals/p4guide/02_config.html#1071378

Answer (score 2):

For P4V version : Rev. Perforce Visual Client/LINUX26X86_64/2012.1/490402

Released on 2012 July 02

Do as follows

Go to Connections -> Edit Current Workspace

In the Basic tab , Workspace Mappings , Right click on the tree and Include Tree.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that there is, you need to open the Workspace view and make your changes there.

Answer (score 0):

Edit your workspace and change the view to include the relevant directory. Although I use P4V everyday and 'Add to client view' seems to ring a bell....

Comment: That's what I was trying to avoid. I'm lazy :-)

Answer (score 0):

Of note, they added this feature into the P4V client at some point. You can now right click on a path in the depot tab and choose "Map to Workspace View...". It will bring up the workspace editor with the path added.